# JQuery selector for multiple sub level inputs elements of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select all the inputs that are in a particular div. The div has inputs at a child depth of 1 and 2. I a able to get the inputs for the first level, but not the second. Here is my code:-

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-11 ajax-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="4">
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="2" type="checkbox" value="Sudo"> Sudo</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="1" type="checkbox" value="Admin"> Admin</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="3" type="checkbox" value="Client"> Client</label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = $('.ajax-form :input').serialize();
  console.log(data);
});
```

My output:

> user_id=4

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrpuawfc/)

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: so you want to select the first input ( the hidden one ) but not the others ?? or do you want to get them all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Reason why your code not working:-***

1.In your code when document is ready, no check-box is checked, that's why there values are not coming in serialized data.

***Solution***:- Add `checked` attribute to the check-boxes like below:-

Example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = $('.ajax-form :input').serialize();
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-11 ajax-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="4">
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="2" type="checkbox" value="Sudo" checked> Sudo</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="1" type="checkbox" value="Admin" checked> Admin</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="3" type="checkbox" value="Client" checked> Client</label>
</div>
```

***Another option to do same:-***

2.Create a button and on the button click try to serialized the div elements data.Then no need to add `checked` attribute. It will work dynamically.

Example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#serialize_div_data').click(function(){
      var data = $('.ajax-form :input').serialize();
      console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="col-xs-11 ajax-form">
      <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="4">
      <label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="2" type="checkbox" value="Sudo"> Sudo</label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="1" type="checkbox" value="Admin"> Admin</label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="3" type="checkbox" value="Client"> Client</label>
</div>
<input type="button" id = "serialize_div_data" value="Click Me to serailized the div data">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
$('.ajax-form :input')
```

this will get value of those check-box which are checked.

Check the update [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/yrpuawfc/2/)

In this I have put the `checked` attribute in one checkbox, and you will get its value in `jquery` code. So to get the chekbox value you have to handle the checked / unchecked event also.

Answer (score 0):

Your code not work because when you load form your checkbox not check so it is not consider form value

try below code when you get data when load page

```
    <div class="col-xs-11 ajax-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="4">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="2" type="checkbox" value="Sudo" checked> Sudo</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="1" type="checkbox" value="Admin" checked> Admin</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="3" type="checkbox" value="Client" checked> Client</label>
    </div>
```